# Beamer and indentation with alltt

Tags: beamer, indentation, verbatim

The following beamer code

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{PROC TEMPLATE for a fancy graph (part 2)}
\begin{alltt}
      rowaxes;
        rowaxis /label = 'Infant Mortality (\%)'
         griddisplay = on;
        rowaxis /label = '' griddisplay = on;
      endrowaxes;
    layout overlay; 
      scatterplot x = unemployment 
        y = infantmortality;
      loessplot x = unemployment
        y = infantmortality/nomarkers;
      loessplot x = unemployment
           y = infantmortality/smooth = 1;
      ellipse  x = unemployment y = infantmortality
             /type = predicted;
     endlayout;
\end{alltt}
\end{frame}
```

Indents as shown until the line starting "ellipse" which is set flush left.  Adding a paragraph marker after "unemployment" does not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code snippet works OK for me, after suitable completion. Could you please post a (complete) [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem?

Comment: A cause for this can be using <tab> instead of spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see any problem, when I create a *complete* document from your code fragment! However, beamer knows the environment `semiverbatim` which can also be used:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{PROC TEMPLATE for a fancy graph (part 2)}
\begin{semiverbatim}
      rowaxes;
        rowaxis /label = 'Infant Mortality (\%)'
         griddisplay = on;
        rowaxis /label = '' griddisplay = on;
      endrowaxes;
    layout overlay; 
      scatterplot x = unemployment 
        y = infantmortality;
      loessplot x = unemployment
        y = infantmortality/nomarkers;
      loessplot x = unemployment
           y = infantmortality/smooth = 1;
      ellipse  x = unemployment y = infantmortality
             /type = predicted;
     endlayout;
\end{semiverbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! semiverbatim solved this problem. I hadn't even heard of this environment.